# php not working under directory of mod_userdir (~/user)

Tags: apache2, php

My php code not working under directory of mod_userdir (~/user) but working fine at /var/www/ , how I can dealing with this problems ? when I open  a php file under ~/user my browser prompt to download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please look in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf, it has this comment:

```
# To re-enable php in user directories comment the following lines
# (from <IfModule ...> to </IfModule>.) Do NOT set it to On as it
# prevents .htaccess files from disabling it.
```

After you changed the file, restart Apache with `service apache2 restart`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `mod_userdir` Apache extension is enabled. Enable by the following command:

```
a2enmod userdir
```

<sup>Prefix with `sudo` if required.</sup>

Then reload/restart Apache (`service apache2 restart`).